# How i can return to My C# window form design

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am coding C# window form application 
i did something  and found the design of my window form called projects.cs
became as shown in picture below[all shown are zeros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bshU.png)
how i can return to my form design

[image]

Comment: try to restart  the visual studio, clean the solution and rebuild.

Comment: when rebuild this error found "CS1056 unexpected character ' in projects"

Comment: what is the modification you made to cause this,  ? , are you using custom controls like telerik ?

Comment: no , and i do not remember what i did but i tried to solve CS1056 error

Comment: sorry but it seems that you need to rebuild that form again idk maybe if you can share it on github or something i can check it for you.

Comment: The error sounds plausible as VS will go to hex mode if the file is a binary file. If it is all `0`s it seems lost. Can you roll back? Git(!!) or windows file history?

Comment: This can occur when your computer unexpectedly crashes or loses power right after saving the project.  That is not supposed to happen with a journaling file system like NTFS, but does happen on some programmers' machines.  What they have in common is never obvious, but you probably want to go shopping for a different anti-malware product.  The code is irretrievably lost, you need to start over again with the backup copy from source control.